# Excel VBA - select multiple columns not in sequential order

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to select **multiple** columns.

Eg. I want to **`select column a, b, d, e, g, h`**

I've tried:

```
Columns("A, B, D, E, G, H").select
```

I get **error** message: **`Type mismatch`**.

Comment: 99% of the time you never need to select cells to work with them.  What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: Reafidy is correct. BTW HL8, are you aware that you can record a macro ;) ?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

`Range("A:B,D:E,G:H").Select`  can help

Edit note: I just saw you have used different column sequence, I have updated my answer

Comment: The title states non sequential, your method would select all columns between `C` and `H`, I do not think this is what the OP is after.

Comment: @HRgiger How can i get the values in those cells to an array?
is this query possible?

 someArray = Range("B4:B9,S4:S9").Value

Answer (score 22):

Some things of top of my head.

**Method 1.**

```
Application.Union(Range("a1"), Range("b1"), Range("d1"), Range("e1"), Range("g1"), Range("h1")).EntireColumn.Select
```

**Method 2.**

```
Range("a1,b1,d1,e1,g1,h1").EntireColumn.Select
```

**Method 3.**

```
Application.Union(Columns("a"), Columns("b"), Columns("d"), Columns("e"), Columns("g"), Columns("h")).Select
```

Comment: **Method 3** is my preference as I find it is also the best solution for working with already defined and named ranges rather than entire columns. `Application.Union.(range1, range2, range3).select` is great.

I think this solution (for copying and pasting purposes) _would_ require that the ranges be identically sized.

Answer (score 3):

Some of the code looks a bit complex to me. This is very simple code to select only the used rows in two discontiguous columns D and H. It presumes the columns are of unequal length and thus more flexible vs if the columns were of equal length.

As you most likely surmised 4=column D and 8=column H

```
Dim dlastRow As Long
Dim hlastRow As Long

dlastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).Row
hlastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 8).End(xlUp).Row
Range("D2:D" & dlastRow & ",H2:H" & hlastRow).Select
```

Hope you find useful - DON'T FORGET THAT COMMA BEFORE THE SECOND COLUMN, AS I DID, OR IT WILL BOMB!!

Answer (score 1):

As a recorded macro.

```
range("A:A, B:B, D:D, E:E, G:G, H:H").select
```

Answer (score 0):

Working on a project I was stuck for some time on this concept - I ended up with a similar answer to Method 1 by @GSerg that worked great.  Essentially I defined two formula ranges (using a few variables) and then used the Union concept.  My example is from a larger project that I'm working on but hopefully the portion of code below can help some other people who might not know how to use the Union concept in conjunction with defined ranges and variables.  I didn't include the entire code because at this point it's fairly long - if anyone wants more insight feel free to let me know.

First I declared all my variables as Public

Then I defined/set each variable

Lastly I set a new variable "SelectRanges" as the Union between the two other FormulaRanges

```
Public r As Long
Public c As Long
Public d As Long
Public FormulaRange3 As Range
Public FormulaRange4 As Range
Public SelectRanges As Range

With Sheet8




  c = pvt.DataBodyRange.Columns.Count + 1

  d = 3

  r = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

Set FormulaRange3 = .Range(.Cells(d, c + 2), .Cells(r - 1, c + 2))
    FormulaRange3.NumberFormat = "0"
    Set FormulaRange4 = .Range(.Cells(d, c + c + 2), .Cells(r - 1, c + c + 2))
    FormulaRange4.NumberFormat = "0"
    Set SelectRanges = Union(FormulaRange3, FormulaRange4)
```