# Excel VBA - How do I select multiple entire columns from defined ranges?

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

## What I am trying to do:

I am trying to copy only certain columns from a spreadsheet based on the header. Rather than do loops to copy each column individually, I am trying to copy a number of columns at once.

## What I have so far:

```
With wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set lasthead1 = .Range("1:1").Find(What:="*", LookAt:=xlPart, MatchCase:=False, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious)
    Set headrng1 = .Range("A1", lasthead1)
    For Each c In headrng1
        If Left(c, 1) = "-" Then c = Mid(c, 2, Len(c) - 1)
        If Left(c, 1) = "+" Then c = Mid(c, 2, Len(c) - 1)
    Next c
    Set PRIhead = headrng1.Find(What:="Priority", LookAt:=xlPart, MatchCase:=False, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlNext)
    Set LOGhead = headrng1.Find(What:="Log Date", LookAt:=xlPart, MatchCase:=False, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlNext)
    Set TYPEhead = headrng1.Find(What:="Type", LookAt:=xlPart, MatchCase:=False, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlNext)
    Set CALLhead = headrng1.Find(What:="Call Status", LookAt:=xlPart, MatchCase:=False, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlNext)
    Set DEShead = headrng1.Find(What:="Description", LookAt:=xlPart, MatchCase:=False, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlNext)
    Set IPKhead = headrng1.Find(What:="IPK Status", LookAt:=xlPart, MatchCase:=False, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlNext)
    .Range(PRIhead, LOGhead, TYPEhead, CALLhead, DEShead, IPKhead).EntireColumn.Copy
End With
```

## The issue:

Appears to be with the following line of code:

```
.Range(PRIhead, LOGhead, TYPEhead, CALLhead, DEShead, IPKhead).EntireColumn.Copy
```

## My Sources:

I used the accepted answer on [This Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8888382/excel-vba-select-multiple-columns-not-in-sequential-order) to put my line of code together.

Comment: can you confirm that _all_ headers are found?

Comment: Yes,during debugging I can see that **ALL** of the headers have been found. That was my first thought. The error I get is `Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment`

Comment: the reason is because `Range` can accept only 2 range object as parameters. Try `Application.Union(PRIhead, LOGhead, TYPEhead, CALLhead, DEShead, IPKhead).EntireColumn.Copy`

Comment: I now get the error `Method 'Union' of object' _Application' failed`

Comment: strange..it works for me..try this: `.Range(PRIhead.Address & "," & LOGhead.Address & "," & TYPEhead.Address & "," & CALLhead.Address & "," & DEShead.Address & "," & IPKhead.Address).EntireColumn.Copy` - is it works?

Comment: That indeed worked, I'm stumped as to why the Application.Union didn't work though after reading about it.

Comment: it's strange, because as far as I know `Method 'Union' of object' _Application' failed` appears only if you tries to union two or more ranges from _different_ sheets. But as I see, all your ranges in single sheet..

Comment: In that case, should it not be `wb.Union(PRIhead, LOGhead, TYPEhead, CALLhead, DEShead, IPKhead).EntireColumn.Copy` as wb is another instance of excel running.

Comment: not quite, `wb` is workbook object, you need _application_ object. Try this one: `wb.Application.Union(PRIhead, LOGhead, TYPEhead, CALLhead, DEShead, IPKhead).EntireColumn.Copy`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow up from comments.

The reason of the issue is because `Range(cell1,[cell2])` object can accept only 2 cells as parameters.

So you need to use

```
wb.Application.Union(PRIhead, LOGhead, TYPEhead, CALLhead, DEShead, IPKhead).EntireColumn.Copy
```

I used `wb.Application.Union` because (as follow up from comments), workbook `wb` is a part of another application object.