# Perform formatting on several not adjacent COLUMNS in excel VBA?

Tags: vba, excel

With my code I want 2 perform formatting over several not adjacent COLUMNS, and I want to make it elegantly in code. Just as it's supposed to be by the book. I'm learning, so I want to learn the right way.
this is how my task looks like:

[image]

I've read [this.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8888382/excel-vba-select-multiple-columns-not-in-sequential-order)
I mean... is there really no way to enumerate column letters in COLUMNS method? no way to do this?

So do I need to use RANGE object to preform my task? Is it correct?

How do I use UNION method in conjunction with "With... End With"
This is my case I guess.
Please explain more in detail than only 1,5 line answer please.
I will need to do the same things with Columns: B, C, G, H.
They will be formatted `.NumberFormat = "#,##0.00"`

```
Option Explicit
Dim VBA As Worksheet
Dim Filter As String
Dim Stock As Variant
Dim Index As Variant
Dim Portfolio As Variant
'   Dim Date as Range

Sub Columns_Formatting()

Set VBA = Workbooks("kgh pricing model thursday.xlsm").Worksheets("VBA")
Filter = "Pliki CSV, *.csv," & "Pliki TXT, *.txt," & "All Files, *.*"
'   Stock = Application.GetOpenFilename(fileFilter:=Filter, FilterIndex:=1, Title:="Choose file with a stock prices")
'   Index = Application.GetOpenFilename(fileFilter:=Filter, FilterIndex:=1, Title:="Choose file with an index values")
'   If Stock = False Or Index = False Then MsgBox "Canceled": Exit Sub

With VBA.Columns("A:A,F:F")     '  here is the error = type mismath
    .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
    .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
    .WrapText = True
    .NumberFormat = "yyyy-mm-dd;@"
    .Orientation = 0
    .AddIndent = False
    .IndentLevel = 0
    .ShrinkToFit = False
    .ReadingOrder = xlContext
    .MergeCells = False
    .ColumnWidth = 12
End With

With VBA.Columns("A;F")
    .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
    .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
    .WrapText = True
    .NumberFormat = "General"
    .Orientation = 0
    .AddIndent = False
    .IndentLevel = 0
    .ShrinkToFit = False
    .ReadingOrder = xlContext
    .MergeCells = False
    .ColumnWidth = 12
End With

With VBA.Range("E2:E" & Rows.Count)
    .HorizontalAlignment = xlGeneral
    .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
    .WrapText = True
    .NumberFormat = "#,##0"
    .Orientation = 0
    .AddIndent = False
    .IndentLevel = 0
    .ShrinkToFit = False
    .ReadingOrder = xlContext
    .MergeCells = False
    .ColumnWidth = 10
End With
```

Comment: yes, instead of `With VBA.Columns("A:A,F:F")` use `With VBA.Range("A:A,F:F")`

Comment: for the second part, just use `With VBA.Range("B:B,C:C,G:G,H:H")` , or shorter `With VBA.Range("B:C,G:H")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [Range object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838238.aspx) with full column references. You might also want to cut down the full column references to the [Worksheet.UsedRange property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840732.aspx) with the [Intersect method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa195772.aspx).

```
With VBA
    With Intersect(.UsedRange, .Range("A:A,F:F"))
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
        .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
        .WrapText = True
        .NumberFormat = "yyyy-mm-dd;@"
        .Orientation = 0
        .AddIndent = False
        .IndentLevel = 0
        .ShrinkToFit = False
        .ReadingOrder = xlContext
        .MergeCells = False
        .ColumnWidth = 12
    End With
End With
```