# Select multiple columns starting from specific row

Tags: vba, excel

My question is very similar to this one but still I don't know how to do It myself.
 I would like to do the same thing as here: [Excel VBA - select multiple columns not in sequential order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8888382/excel-vba-select-multiple-columns-not-in-sequential-order) except for the thing that I don't need entire column, but entire column starting from the specific row number.

So in my case, I would like to have in range multiple columns starting from the row number 30 to the end of each selected column. But not all columns on sheet, just few.

Comment: Try `Range("A20:B1000,D20:E1000,G20:H1000").Select`

Comment: A20:B1000 - which column would be selected in this case ? for example I will need C, J, K , L, O how would you write It that way?

Comment: You should be able to read the comment and understand what’s happening. You can translate that in literal terms. You can easily record a macro to figure out how to do this.

Comment: Its not unfortunately. I am writing my first macro ever. Its not logical If I will need column A why would range be A20:B1000, or what else he was thinking I am not sure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the Intersection of the rows and columns.

```
Dim lr As Long

With Worksheets("sheet10")
    lr = .Cells.Find(what:="*", after:=.Cells(1), _
                     SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
    Intersect(.Range("C:C, J:L, O:O"), .Range("30:" & lr)).Select
End With
```

Answer (score 1):

You can definitely use a macro recording to simulate what you want for the first column selected, then modify to fit your needs

This is sample code that will do what you want using predefined constants

Modify the constants for your list of columns and start row

```
Sub CustomColumnSelection()

    ' Describe what columns you want to select
    Const ColumnList    As String = "A,C,D"

    ' Row to start at
    Const StartAtRow    As Long = 5

    Dim lngLastRow      As Long
    Dim arrColumns      As Variant
    Dim strSelect       As String
    Dim i               As Integer

    ' Create an array to hold columns
    arrColumns = Split(ColumnList, ",")

    ' Calculate last row of data in column
    With ActiveSheet
       lngLastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, arrColumns(0)).End(xlUp).Row
    End With

    ' Define first column to select
    strSelect = arrColumns(0) & StartAtRow
    ' and add rows to last ne found above
    strSelect = strSelect  & ":" & arrColumns(0) & lngLastRow

    ' Add rest of columns to selection list
    For i = 1 To UBound(arrColumns)
        strSelect = strSelect & "," & arrColumns(i) & StartAtRow & ":" & arrColumns(i) & lngLastRow
    Next i

    Range(strSelect).Select

End Sub
```

Here's [one of many sites with good example excel-vba code](https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s9/win005.htm) for selecting special cells

Comment: i did something else to be honest, just took one column and added offset, so It worked for me, and It was quite simple

Comment: If either answer helped at all it would be great for an up-vote. If you have your own answer, nothing wrong with submitting your code in your own answer and describing how it works. Everyone benefits