# Using VBScript.vbs to remove Excel columns based on column names

Tags: excel, vbscript

Rather than resorting to `object.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A:A").EntireColumn.Delete` within a Visual Basic Script and repeat the syntax *n* times on targeted columns, I was wondering if there are more efficient ways to delete all the columns in an Excel workbook except some few of them based on the column names (e.g `Date`, `Id`, etc).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Excel VBA - select multiple columns not in sequential order](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8888382/11683)

Answer (score 0):

Well, here is what you didn't ask for... *VBA*

But maybe this can give you insight on how to approach the problem

```
Sub deleter()
    Dim col
    Dim header
    Dim exclusions As Object
    Set exclusions = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    ' add column names you want to save
    exclusions.Add "Date", 1
    exclusions.Add "Id", 1

    ' iterate thru columns
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").UsedRange
        For col = .Columns.Count To 1 Step -1
            ' save column name (row 1)
            header = Trim(CStr(.Cells(1, col).Value))
            ' if not in dictionary, delete column
            If Not exclusions.exists(header) Then
                .Columns(col).Delete
            End If
        Next
    End With

End Sub
```

This approach assumes the column names are in Row 1 for each column