# Select multiple table columns to a range variable if row2 value is greater than threshold

Tags: excel, vba

I am currently working with a pre-selected range of data but I need to make it dynamic. Need to select a range of multiple columns in a table and assign it to a range variable, the condition being that the row2 values are greater than some fixed threshold.
The columns may be non continuous.
I tried to do in the following way but getting errors (not exact code)

```
range=nothing
for each column in table
  if column row2.value>fixed then
  range = range + column
  end if
next column
range.select
```

### Thanks for any help.

Thanks, Following the comments I tried-

```
Dim tbl As ListObject
Dim col As ListColumn
Dim checkcol As Range


Set tbl = Sheets("Sheet1").ListObjects(1)
For Each col In tbl.ListColumns
   If WorksheetFunction.IsNumber(ActiveSheet.ListObjects(1).DataBodyRange(2, col.Index).Value) Then
   Set checkcol = Union(checkcol, 
   ActiveSheet.ListObjects(1).ListColumns(col.Index).Range)
   End If
Next col
checkcol.Select
```

Now, I am getting a single error on 4th last line,

```
Set checkcol = Union(checkcol, ActiveSheet.ListObjects(1).ListColumns(col.Index).Range)
```

Error - Run time error 5, Invalid Procedure call or argument, Can't I union nothing with a column? The error is occurring the first time this line runs.

Comment: `range = range + column` doesn't make sense if you're working with a `Range`... `Union` maybe.

Comment: Have you seen [Excel VBA - select multiple columns not in sequential order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8888382/excel-vba-select-multiple-columns-not-in-sequential-order)?  There are many ways to do this (including a `Union()` answer that was not selected by the OP, but still ahs good info).