# Excel VBA hide several columns in 1 line of code

Tags: excel, vba

I want to hide several columns (that's not close to each other) in 1 line (shown below) in VBA but it doesn't work. What's wrong with it?

```
Columns("A, C:D").hidden = True
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `Range.EntireColumn`.

```
Range("A:A,C:D").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
```

[This thread is similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8888382/excel-vba-select-multiple-columns-not-in-sequential-order), and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8888462/9245853) demonstrates that `Union` is another option here as well.

Note that `.EntireColumn` is necessary; omitting it will throw a

> Run-time error '1004':
>
> Unable to set the Hidden property of the Range class.

Answer (score 1):

### Hide Columns Using `Union`

- The best answer is already posted so here is kind of a cheating one: it is one line, but uses a function (with 'several' lines).

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub hideColumns()
    CombinedColumns(ActiveSheet, "A,C,H,K:M,O,R:U").Hidden = True
End Sub

Function CombinedColumns( _
    ByVal ws As Worksheet, _
    ByVal ColumnsList As String, _
    Optional ByVal Delimiter As String = ",") _
As Range
    Dim Cols() As String: Cols = Split(ColumnsList, Delimiter)
    Dim rg As Range
    Dim n As Long
    For n = 0 To UBound(Cols)
        If rg Is Nothing Then
            Set rg = ws.Columns(Cols(n))
        Else
            Set rg = Union(rg, ws.Columns(Cols(n)))
        End If
    Next n
    If Not rg Is Nothing Then
        Set CombinedColumns = rg.EntireColumn
    End If
End Function
```